# Switch System.Type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have class which contains Dictionary. 
I have following method to get the value from Delegate depend of Exception type:

```
public static async Task<Response> GetResponseAsync<TException>(HttpContext httpContext, TException exception)
            where TException : Exception
        {
            if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(exception.GetType()))
            {
                //TODO: Handle global
            }

            var @delegate = Dictionary[exception.GetType()];

            switch (@delegate.Method.ReturnType)
            {
                case Type type when type == typeof(IHandler<TException>):
                    return await ((IHandler<TException>)@delegate.DynamicInvoke()).HandleAsync(null, exception);
                case Type type when type == typeof(Task<Response>):
                    return await (Task<Response>)@delegate.DynamicInvoke(httpContext, exception);
                case Type type when type == typeof(Response):
                    return (Response)@delegate.DynamicInvoke();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

I added IndexOutOfRangeException type into Dictionary with the delegate which return instance of IndexOutOfRangeExceptionHandler class.

```
public class IndexOutOfRangeExceptionHandler : IHandler<IndexOutOfRangeException>
    {
        public Task<Response> HandleAsync(HttpContext context, IndexOutOfRangeException exception)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Response(HttpStatusCode.AlreadyReported, $"{context.Request.Path} failed with {exception.GetType().FullName}. Catched by {nameof(IndexOutOfRangeExceptionHandler)}"));
        }
    }
```

When I call GetResponseAsync the breakpoint goes into third case which is senseless. However when I try to do the same check in Immediate window compiler says its false and should not enter the third case.

[image]

Why does the breakpoint hit the third instead of first case?

Comment: It is a fairly notorious debugger problem that keeps popping up repeatedly in various ways.  When you use the Debug > Step Into command then you'll see it doesn't actually execute the delegate.  Underlying cause is this method being *async* and there is a bit of extra machine code that doesn't have a corresponding line in the source code.  So the debugger doesn't have a good cue to highlight the correct source line.  Just keep going, this isn't a problem with your code and nothing actually goes wrong.